# After approving the payment redirects on a blank page

Tags: woocommerce

I have a shop made with WooCommerce.

The problem arises when the payment is approved by the payment gateway, redirects me to a blank page, which shows no error.

Attached is the error line that generates the error log.

> payment_method was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be
>   accessed directly.  Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp,
>   WP->main, WP->parse_request, do_action_ref_array('parse_request'),
>   WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   rest_api_loaded, WP_REST_Server->serve_request,
>   WP_REST_Server->dispatch, call_user_func,
>   PlacetoPay\PaymentMethod\GatewayMethod->endpointPlacetoPay,
>   PlacetoPay\PaymentMethod\GatewayMethod->returnProcess,
>   WC_Order->payment_complete, WC_Order->save,
>   WC_Order->status_transition,
>   do_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array,
>   actualiza_estado_pedidos_a_completado,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong.  This message was
>   added in version 3.0

Comment: "Order properties should not be accessed directly", this seems to me that a custom code or a plugin has not been updated. ¿Are your plugins updated, try to disable them to see if there is some kind of conflict? ¿Have you add some custom code? ¿What happen on your site before this error appeared?

Comment: The only symptom is that the moment the merchant approves the payment, by redirecting to the thank you page/checkout, the page is blank. The personalized code I added and immediately deleted, was to update the status of the order from processing to completing once the payment is authorized and from there, is generating it, the doubt is that I no longer have that fragment of code.

Comment: Do you have a backup? Maybe broke after that modification. Any error that the log shows? Without that, I think is going to be difficult to help you.

Comment: In that case, I've already restored the backup, but the same problem of showing me the blank page when I redirect to the thank you page continues. And on the error log, the fragment I copied at the beginning of this question, is the one that generates the error log.